# Optuna in-memory paralellization

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing, hpc, hyperparameters, optuna

I am performing hyperparameter optimization with Optuna (from within rl-zoo) and have some questions about parallelization.

1. In the docs, it is recommended to use process based (-> distributed) parallelization with a shared storage, which is some local SQL Database in the examples. It also says that the study should be created with the `storage` argument, meaning to set the storage argument to something that is not None I guess. Setting it to None (which is the default) will set the storage to be in-memory-storage. If we look at the code of `create_study`, we find the following comment:
   `storage: Database URL. If this argument is set to None, in-memory storage is used, and the :class: ~optuna.study.Study will not be persistent.` **Does that mean that the parallelization plainly not works with in-memory storage**? Or just something like that the Study won't be available to inspect after it's done, as if it would be saved in a database? So that it kinda vanishes after it's done. I am working on an HPC Cluster and have trouble setting up the SQL Server due to permissions, that's why I am asking.
2. Alternatively one can parallelize thread based with `--n-jobs > 1`, does that conflict in any way with the distributed approach or can I just combine the two as I want?